# Error: length(x) not equal to 1

Tags: r, ggvis

I'm trying to plot some data for eventual statistical analysis. Currently I am using `ggvis` to plot the data because I saw some cool interactivity and ease of use the function has.

Anyways, this is the code that is giving me the error *Error: length(x) not equal to 1*:

```
ggvis(myfile, myfile$Shipment.Date, myfile$Act.Ctns)
```

sample data

```
          Shipment.Date                  Act.Ctns
3326      3/3/2015  Wm Eu Apple 2L       60
3327      3/3/2015 Tp Euro 2 Layer      420
3328      3/3/2015     Tpe 3-Layer       80
3329      3/3/2015        14/3 Bgs      145
3330      3/4/2015             T/P      196
3331      3/4/2015  Wm Eu Apple 2L    1,260
3332      3/4/2015 Tp Euro 2 Layer      360
3333      3/4/2015        14/3 Bgs    1,355
```

here is some sample data, I just printed myfile and took a copy of it.
I'm completely new to R unclear how to fix this issue. Please let me know if I need to convert a variable or do something else for `ggvis` to work. Thanks!

I've looked at ?ggvis, but it appears I've met all the criteria for the funtion, and watched someone do the exact same thing with a similar time series data set in another video.

Comment: we need to see your code, we need some example data.

Comment: Have you tried making your code mirror what you read in the Examples section of `?ggvis`?  All the example code contains tildes and no dollar signs, for example, which I don't see in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're specifying the aesthetics incorrectly. Try

```
ggvis(myfile, ~Shipment.Date, ~Act.Ctns)
```

as in:

```
ggvis(mtcars, ~mpg, ~wt)
```

[image]

Comment: So when I run the code the way you told me to, which is also the way I saw in a new video, I get the following error:

Error in f(vis, ...) : y variable (weights) must be numeric.

Comment: Well, is `myfile$Act.Ctns` numeric? I think there may be a problem with the waay to are importing your data. What is the output of `sapply(myfile,class)`? How about `summary(myfile)`?

Comment: Okay, all 3 are factors, I just converted the cartons to numeric using as.numeric() and it finally plots so thanks! However, I have a new problem, which may require a new question instead of an extension edit of this one...my graph does not include the shipment dates along the x axis, only 1 bar with no labels

Comment: You could try `myfile$Shipment.Date <- as.Date(myfile$Shipment.Date, format="%m/%d/%Y")` but I'm worried about all that random text. Which column does it belong to?

Comment: That actually worked! Running myfile$Shipment.date also prints all the dates with no NA's or missing dates it seems so I think all is good. Thank you so much!

Comment: If it works, great. But you should know that you can't convert a factor to numeric using `as.numeric(...)`. That returns the codes, not the levels. You have to use `as.numeric(as.character(...))`.